# Login in/ Sign up Passport Js

Tags: node.js

so, I've been having this trouble for the longest I can't make my sign in/ login in to work. Here's my code in my passport js:

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/User");

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() });
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { msg: `Email ${email} not found.` });
        }
        if (!user.password) {
          return done(null, false, {
            msg:
              "Your account was registered using a sign-in provider. To enable password login, sign in using a provider, and then set a password under your user profile.",
          });
        }
        user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
          }
          return done(null, false, { msg: "Invalid email or password." });
        });
      } catch (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user._id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(id);
      done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      done(err);
    }
  });
};
```

does anyone know how to solve this?

Im expecting for the login/sign up to go through.

Comment: Try adding some console.log() statements or debug the application to see which parts you are or aren't reaching. To improve your question you need to provide more details on what isn't working. Work on isolation as well, try removing mongoose and database queries, for instance.